# Is there a way to derive the second linearly independent solution to ODE whose characteristic quadratic has double roots?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that one can use an *[ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz)* to determine that $te^{rt}$ is a solution to the ODE $a\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+cx=0$ where $r$ is the double root of the characteristic polynomial. Is there a way this can be derived explicitly without such an "educated guess"?

Comment: @Moo I meant $cx$ (with $d=0$). I'll fix that now.

Comment: Variation of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let the general solution have the form $ x(t) = y(t) e^{rt} $, then
$$ \begin{align}
0 &= a\ddot{x} + b\ddot{x} + cx \\
&= ( a(\ddot{y} + 2r\dot{y} + r^2 y ) + b(\dot{y}+ry) + cy )e^{rt} \\
0&= a\ddot{y} + (2ra+b)\dot{y} + (ar^2+br+c)y 
\end{align} $$
If $r$ is a simple root of $ar^2+br+c$, the equation reduces to
$$ a\ddot{y} + (2ra+b)\dot{y} = 0 , $$
which we can integrate once to get
$$ a\dot{y} + (2ra+b)y = A $$
for some constant $A$. Now, if $A$ is a double root, we also have $2ra+b = 0$, either from multiplying out the brackets in $a(x-r)^2$ and equating coefficients, or using that the derivative of the quadratic also vanishes at a repeated root. Either way, the equation now reduces to
$$ a\dot{y} = A , $$
which integrates to $ay=At+B$, which on resubstituting gives the general solution for $x$. A similar approach works for any linear differential equation where you know one solution: this process is called *reduction of order*.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy is to eliminate the exponential factor, which can be done as follows:

The equation with a double root can be brought into the form $$x''-2rx'+r^2x=0$$ Now set $y=x'-rx$ so that $$y'-ry=0$$ whence $y=Ae^{rt}$

We are then faced with $$x'-rx=Ae^{rt}$$ or $$x'e^{-rt}-rxe^{-rt}=A$$

Now set $z=xe^{-rt}$ so that $z'=-rz+x'e^{-rt}$ and we have $$z'+rz-rz=z'=A$$

And the solution to $z'=A$ is $z=At+B$ whence $x=Ate^{rt}+Be^{rt}$